# How to save celery task to a temporary db which will then be updated to the master db

Tags: python, django, postgresql, celery, psycopg2

What is a good way to compare new data with old data which is updated everyday with Django ORM? Basically I have a scraper which fetches hackathons everyday (basically just a celery task) and I want the newest to be unioned it with my master database which has the latest fetched hackathons from yesterday. I don't want to destroy my master database and then just upload everything that I just fetched since that seems wasteful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This more seems data comparison and no need to save celery task in db.
Ideal use case to save celery task in db is when that task it self needs to be scheduled.

For data comparison you can make use of hash (MD5, SSA1 etc). This will speed up the data comparison.

1. for existing records in db, create one column to store hash of that entire record. use algorithm of your choice  MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, Snefru etc to hash.
2. when new data is received/processed by celery task, create a hash of that record too.
3. now compare this hash created in 2nd step with hash of all exiting records.
4. if there's a match found then data already exists in master.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, for now what I am doing is as I'm receiving the data I am saving it to my db only if .get() returns DoesNotExist. Would comparing hashes be faster then calling a get() function for the record?

Comment: are you comparing each field of record from db with get()? if so use hash and return hash of the record then compare it with hash of obtained result from celery task. if no match then store new data.